# Does fusing multiple cards reward multiple bonuses?

Tags: mobius-final-fantasy

If I use fusion to merge cards, and the skillseed chance is 100%, should I just fuse single cards multiple times, or does fusing multiple cards at once have a chance of unlocking more than 1 skillseed?

Perhaps better explained with an example.

**Dust Ripper**

- Skillseeds 1/5
- Fuse Dust Ripper x1 - Skillseed chance 100%

This should unlock a skillseed.

**Dust Ripper**

- Skillseeds 1/5
- Fuse Dust Ripper x2 - Skillseed chance 100% on both fused cards

Does this unlock 2 skillseeds? Or should I do two separate fusions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only unlocks 1 skillseed. If you're only interested in unlocking skillseeds, then you should do two separate fusions.

But... you might still decide to fuse multiple cards because there are other things that unlock as well, like ability level, which typically has a lesser chance of unlocking compared to skillseeds. So, with your Dust Ripper example, you'll have a 100% success chance for the skillseed fusion, but only a 50% chance for the ability fusion to succeed. So, there will likely be a point where you're going to fuse additional cards despite already having a 100% chance for the skillseed fusion (or you've already unlocked all of the skillseeds).

Comment: It is also useful to point out that the higher the skillseed/ability level you are trying to unlock, the lower the chance. This is fairly obvious, but worth noting. At the higher tiers, fusing two low cards that would give, say 10% chance to your best one, would produce one card that would give 20% chance. Doing this you can overcome the limiting factor of only being able to fuse 5 cards at a time.